# MongoDB - Only fetch the first item in an array on a populated document - e.g. user.populate('posts', 'images.0')

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

Say I'm fetching a user with a `posts` field. Each `post` has a field `images`. I want to populate the posts on the user, but only fetch the first image from each post. How can I do this? I've given the following as an example that does not work:

```
db.User.findOne().populate('posts', 'images.0')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) projection operator to specifies the number of elements in an array to return in the query result.

```
db.User.findOne().populate('posts', { 'images': { '$slice': 1 } })
```

---

If you want to select direct string instead of array of string use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) or [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/index.html) aggregation operator Starting from MongoDB 4.4,

- `$arrayElemAt`

```
db.User.findOne().populate('posts', { 'images': { '$arrayElemAt': ["$images", 0] } })
```

- `$first`

```
db.User.findOne().populate('posts', { 'images': { '$first': "$images" } })
```